# How to use redux store, reducers and actions in react js app which is outside from src package?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, webpack-4

I'm creating app which shares a code between **react js** app and **react native** app. I have put my **redux** reducers, actions and store into some shared directory which I want to use in **react js** app and **react native** app. I'm able to access it in **react native** app using **rn-cli.config.js**, but I didn't find any configuration to use redux files into **react js** app. Is this possible using **webpack**? What configuration I have to make?